# Как добавить одно поле через view а другие с request django

Tags: django, form

я новичок в Django, и сейчас хочу сделать форму. Дело в том, что у формы один элемент должен задаваться с `view`,а остальные пользователь должен сам

*это views.py*

```
def form_Profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompanyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('home2')
    else:
        form = CompanyForm()
        form.user=request.user
    return render(request, 'AdminCompany/first_form_to_Company.html', {
        'form': form})
```

*вот models.py*

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True);
    name_of_company=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='');
    logo=models.ImageField(upload_to=Company_directory)
    description=models.TextField();
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

*вот forms.py*

```
class CompanyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['user','name_of_company', 'logo', 'description']
```

*вот first_form_to_Company.html*

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Form of your page </h4>
            <p class="card-description">
                Please 
            </p>
        <form class="forms-sample" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Названия компаний</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_name_of_company" placeholder="Название">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Logo</label>
                <input type="file" name="myfile" id='id_logo'>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Кратко раскажите о компаний</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_description">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gradient-primary mr-2">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-light">Cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Пользователь первым делам авторизуется, а потом попадает на эту страницу, и заполняет форму. Тут как вы видите пользователь не заполняет поле `user`, оно должно браться с предыдущего `request`.

Я взяла код `view` в stackoverflow, но он не помог.

Comment: Что конкретно не работает? Выдает ошибку какую-либо или сохраняет компанию без пользователя?

Comment: ничего,он на  ту же страницу закидывает,и не сохраняет в базе данных. Никакой ошибки не выдает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**views.py:**

```
def form_Profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompanyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('home2')
    else:
        form = CompanyForm()
    return render(request, 'AdminCompany/first_form_to_Company.html', {
        'form': form})
```

**models.py:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    name_of_company=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    logo=models.ImageField(upload_to=Company_directory)
    description=models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

**forms.py без изменений.**

**шаблон:**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Form of your page </h4>
            <p class="card-description">
                Please 
            </p>
        {{ form.errors }}
        <form class="forms-sample" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Названия компаний</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_of_company"  id="id_name_of_company" placeholder="Название">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Logo</label>
                <input type="file" name="myfile" id='id_logo' name="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Кратко раскажите о компаний</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="id_description">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gradient-primary mr-2">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-light">Cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает